# Is this a valid Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Is this a valid javascript object?

```
var sections = 
{
    { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
};
```

How would I access this?

I will know the name ('SERVER' etc) and will want to get the true or false value for the isKeyValuePair property.

Is there a better layout for this object whereby I can still access the keyvaluepair property based on a search of the name?

Thanks a lot

Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a valid javascript object?

No. Inside an object literal you need to have `key: value` pairs.

> Is there a better layout for this object whereby I can still access the keyvaluepair property based on a search of the name?

This would be valid:

```
var sections = 
[
    { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
];
```

In which case you could loop over the array until you found the entry you wanted.

You'd probably want to express it in this way through:

```
var sections = 
{
    SERVER: true,
    TYPES: false,
    USERS: false
};
```

Then you would just `sections.SERVER` or `sections['SERVER']` (and thus also `var section = "SERVER"; sections[section];` since you might have the key name in a variable)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. You should suplly the inner objects with keys, or us an array of objects:

```
// key-value pairs
var sections = 
{
    o1: { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    o2: { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    o3: { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
};
console.log(sections.o1.name); //=> 'SERVER'

// array
var sections = 
[
    { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
];
console.log(sections[0].name); //=> 'SERVER'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid.

You can use either

```
var sections = 
{
    s1: { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    s2: { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    s3: { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
};
```

and acces as `sections.s1`, ...

or

```
var sections = 
[
    { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
];
```

and `sections[0]`, ...

Comment: Again. Thank you for you helpful and quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't a valid object.If it was structured like this:

```
var sections = {
    prop11: { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    prop2: { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    prop3: { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
};
```

It would be correct. However it looks like what you really want is an array. Try using the following:

```
var sections = 
[
    { name: 'SERVER', isKeyValuePair: true },
    { name: 'TYPES', isKeyValuePair: false },
    { name: 'USERS', isKeyValuePair: false }
];
```